# How to multiply matrix row by vector element in pypark 2.2.0

Tags: python, matrix, vector, pyspark, multiplication

I am trying to multiply each matrix row by its corresponding element in a given vector using pyspark 2.2.0.

For example in `numpy` I can do this as follows:

```
foo = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
bar = np.array([[2],[3]])
bar * foo
```

Results in:

```
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [12, 15, 18]])
```

Note that I don't want to do a dot product. It's simply multiplying every element in a matrix row by the corresponding element in a vector.

Is there some way of doing this in pyspark 2.2.0? I have tried multiple things but couldn't quite get what I wanted. I guess one could do it with a `map` but somehow that feels wrong.

Is there some better way?

Comment: Can you share some information of the matrix you are working with? Is the matrix distributed?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to use. I am just wondering if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it join two dataframes row by row for instance, and then use a `UDF` to multiply each element of the `ArrayType` by an `IntegerType`:

First let's create dataframes with a row index:

```py
foo_df = sc.parallelize(foo.tolist()).zipWithIndex().toDF()
bar_df = sc.parallelize(bar.tolist()).zipWithIndex().toDF()
```

Now to join them and get the final result:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
mul = psf.udf(lambda xx,y: [x * y for x in xx], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
foo_df.join(bar_df, '_2')\
    .select(mul(foo_df._1, bar_df._1[0]))\
    .show()

    +-------------------+
    |<lambda>(_1, _1[0])|
    +-------------------+
    |          [2, 4, 6]|
    |       [12, 15, 18]|
    +-------------------+
```